# folder not visible

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, file-management

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2, running Android 2.3.

I have folder named `usbStorage`. After the firmware to latest version (via Kies), I can't see the `usbStorage` folder. When I mount the storage via USB mass storage mode, I can see that folder with all my content. I tried to copy some files in that folder, but no luck. When I connect the phone to MTP mode, I can see the folder but it's empty.

Is there a way to get back that folder? I can move all my content to another folder, but then I need to rewrite my applications that depend on that.

Comment: here are my two cents, the file browser samsung bundles with their firmware doesn't always show you all the files tree. you might want to try moving the content of the folder to another location visible to the file browser, or, if you're feeling adventurous, root your device and install a better app like root browser.

Comment: then why they showed that folder in 2.3.3 version? Also i deleted that folder and after remount memory to pc, the folder was created again. And also my own application can't see that folder. looks like it is locked by OS. I moved all content to new folder.